# Binary Literals in C++

Tags: c++, string, binary, integer, literals

Can I add binary literal prefix in c++ before a user input int value.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
 int n1;
 cin>>n1;
 string s1 = to_string(n1); 
  string s2 = "0b";
string s=s2+s1;
int n=stoi(s);
cout<<n;
return 0;
}
```

I tried this but failed as stoi() only reads 0 and skips the rest

Answer (score 3):

There's still no way of reading a binary number directly from standard input. Any auto-detection of the radix does not support `"0b"`, so `stoi()` stops when `'b'` is reached.

If `s` is a `std::string` read from standard input (`std::cin >> s;` perhaps), *without* the `"0b"` prefix, then you can use

```
#include <cstdlib>
char* end;
long n = std::strtol(s.c_str(), &end, 2/*radix of 2 denotes binary*/);
```

checking the pointer `end` in case there are invalid binary digits in `s`.

Note that I'm using `strtol` rather than `stoi` as an `int` can have a upper limits as small as 32767.